# How do I tell where the user's home directory is, in Dart?

Tags: dart

I want to store a small bit of information in a file, persisted between runs of a command-line app. Probably the best location is a small file in the user's home directory.

I'd like to write a property/config file into a user's home directory. How can I tell, for Windows, Mac, and Linux, what the user's home directory is? I am using Dart.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Identify the OS then use the designated environment variable for that particular OS. You can read the OS/environment variables from [platform](https://www.dartlang.org/dart-by-example/#os-and-hardware-information). For e.g. :

1. `OS : String os = Platform.operatingSystem;` Various checks like `isLinux`, `isAndroid` are given
2. `Map<String, String> envVars = Platform.environment;`

An example:

```
import 'dart:io' show Platform, stdout;

void main() {
  String os = Platform.operatingSystem;
  String home = "";
  Map<String, String> envVars = Platform.environment;
  if (Platform.isMacOS) {
    home = envVars['HOME'];
  } else if (Platform.isLinux) {
    home = envVars['HOME'];
  } else if (Platform.isWindows) {
    home = envVars['UserProfile'];
  }
  stdout.writeln(home);
}
```

Home dirs taken from here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory

Answer (score 2):

I don't have access to a windows machine, but I found this logic in pub:

```
  if (Platform.environment.containsKey('PUB_CACHE')) {
    cacheDir = Platform.environment['PUB_CACHE'];
  } else if (Platform.operatingSystem == 'windows') {
    var appData = Platform.environment['APPDATA'];
    cacheDir = path.join(appData, 'Pub', 'Cache');
  } else {
    cacheDir = '${Platform.environment['HOME']}/.pub-cache';
  }
```

Looks like for Linux and Mac, we can do:

`Platform.environment['HOME']`

For Windows, it's better to find a location inside of `Platform.environment['APPDATA']`

Comment: `AppData` is one of several "Special Folders" for storing User Data on Windows.  It's good to review them and pick the one that best suites your needs - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_folder

Answer (score 2):

This will do:

```
String get userHome =>
    Platform.environment['HOME'] ?? Platform.environment['USERPROFILE'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to other answers:

```dart
// Get the home directory or null if unknown.
String homeDirectory() {
  switch (Platform.operatingSystem) {
    case 'linux':
    case 'macos':
      return Platform.environment['HOME'];
    case 'windows':
      return Platform.environment['USERPROFILE'];
    case 'android':
      // Probably want internal storage.
      return '/storage/sdcard0';
    case 'ios':
      // iOS doesn't really have a home directory.
      return null;
    case 'fuchsia':
      // I have no idea.
      return null;
    default:
      return null;
  }
}
```

You can tweak how it behaves according to your needs. I did try and figure out the answer for Fuchsia but I can't work out if it even has home directories to be honest!